# Chaplin cannot find jQuery on Backbone.$ (Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got body)

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, browserify, chaplinjs

I have Chaplin/Backbone project which I'm switching from RequireJS to CommonJS (with Browserify).

When I try to load the app in the browser I get `Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got body`.  This seems to be because `Backbone.$` is undefined.

I'm already doing the following before requiring my app and/or any Chaplin files:

```
var jQuery = require('jquery'),
    Backbone = require('backbone');

Backbone.$ = jQuery;
```

So this should be loading jQuery, and if I inspect Backbone.$ it is there.  However Chaplin seems to either reset `Backbone.$` to undefined, or is using a different instance of Backbone though that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Does Chaplin depend on Backbone? It may be the case that you have two Backbone libs in a bundle — one from your deps and one from Chaplin's deps. Try to execute `npm dedupe` before running browserify, that will dedupe packages in a dependency graph and will end up with a single Backbone lib.

Comment: Yes, Chaplin depends on Backbone. `npm dedupe` didn't work however you were on the right track, the Backbone version within the Chaplin package was being used, so manually removing that did the trick.

Comment: if `npm dedupe` doesn't work for you then both Chaplin and you are depending on different versions of Backbone, otherwise `npm dedupe` would remove one of the Backbone.

Comment: What we've found is that you have to ensure that you have Backbone.$ = require('jquery') in every single module where you use require('chaplin').  I'm going to guess you've missed at least one, and if that module happens to run first, it will fail.   I would live to find a way to avoid this boilerplate code, but I'm just not seeing how.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Chaplin is not using the same Backbone object as yours. Indeed, Chaplin requires Backbone 1.0.0 and you rely on a greater version (presumably 1.1.2).

Thus, when you `require('backbone')`, you are requiring the 1.1.2 Backbone object, whereas, when Chaplin calls `require('backbone')` in its context, Backbone 1.0.0 is returned.

That's two different objects, and the later one will have `Backbone.$ === undefined`, whatever changes you make to the first.

A solution is to use the same version as Chaplin: change your package.json to use Backbone 1.0.0, and use `npm install`. This will only install Backbone in your *node_modules* directory. You will then require the same object as Chaplin.

Another solution is to force Chaplin to use the same version as yours - but that might break some of its components. Simply remove the *node_modules/chaplin/node_modules/backbone* directory. But, again, this fix is really hacky as you are not supposed to change files under the *node_modules* directory.